# Fast way to run shell commands

Tags: java, shell, exec

I'm working on a Java program that should repeatedly kill two processes as soon as possible, as they keep restarting when killed. Of course it shouldn't use too much CPU Time. I've written pretty much the same Program in python and it works well using some 5% of CPU.
I started using `Runtime.exec` with `"ps -ax"` to list all running processes and then search the string for the unwanted processes' name and then run exec with `"killall -9" + process_name` to kill it. This was just the first way i could think of, any ideas are appreciated.
But when i executed the code my computer kept running hot and after some timing tests i found out the `exec` command takes some 15 to 25 ms. Now why does it take that long and is there a faster way to do the job?
Btw i use mac os and don't care if the solution isn't platform-independant.

Comment: Would it be better to stop the processes restarting in the first place?

Comment: I have no idea why you would need to do such a thing. But if you really must, why choose Java? It's not well suited for this kind of task.

Comment: 25ms isn't too much, i guess those processes you're trying to kill waste more resources when they start

Comment: (Emil Vikström) It's two daemons i don't want but as i'm not admin i think i have to kill them repeatedly
(tofarr) Yes, but how could i prevent them from restarting. I'm not admin but i own the processes, so i can kill them. @MichałKosmulski
 
1. because its easy to start. my python script works fine but i always have to start up IDLE to run it and with java i could just create a jar or class file. I also wrote a tiny java program which starts my tiny python script in the same folder which i could zip to share but it seemt silly to me.
2. i'm learning java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that Java is definitely not the right tool for this job.  I also agree with others that this seems like a pretty silly thing to do in the first place.  If it were me I would focus on getting the daemons to not run in the first place.

I would just write a bash script, which has all the functionality you need, and would save some of the process creation time.  You could feed the output of ps into grep to get just the processes you need to eliminate, then pass that to kill.

You can make it even cheaper to run if you [use ps parameters](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps) to select the right processes by name or user or group.